# Very spiky data with asymmetric noise. Smoothing and Filtering seems to raise average [Matlab/Python]

Tags: python, matlab, filter, filtering, noise

I have some data from a tilt meter. I use an ADC to log the data and I want to see if it's possible to do all the filtering from the software end post data-logging.

**Background:** My problem is that when the tilt meter is powered by a battery, the noise seems to be symmetric and vary about a mean value so the filtering returns the measured value to a very good accuracy. However, when I use the mains to power it, the data is more noisy and more irregular, the variations are bigger and produce asymmetric spikes. So using moving averages and filters tends to give a value far away from the actual measured value.

**Comparison of data using two methods:**

[image: Comparison]

**What analog readings of +1, -1 and 0 look like:**

[image: analog readings]

In the first image, the meter reads a constant of about -0.7. The mains seems to add asymmetric noise above it. Noise changes depending on the polarity of signal.

Are there any good filters for data like this? Moving averages and traditional filters don't seem to do the job because of the nature of the noise? (It's a bit harder to explain the nature of the noise but hopefully the image shows it).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: i could only think in a minimum envelope class of signals for the mains case. I am afraid though that it is just like taking the minimum envelope of the battery case too. The original signal is, unfortunately, lost.

Comment: @hypfco thanks! I had just stumbled on that before posting my question but my version of Matlab doesn't have the envelope function. Do you know if there is an equivalent Python function?

Answer (score 0):

Simply try with any of these prototypes:

```
rng(113);
x=-0.7+randn(100,1);
a=0.8
xc(1)=0;
xhr(1)=0;
for i=2:100
    xc(i,1)=a*xc(i-1)+(1-a)*x(i-1);
    xr(i,1)=min([x(i) xc(i)]);
    xhr(i,1)=a*xhr(i-1)+(1-a)*xr(i-1);
end
plot([x xc xr xhr])
```

EDIT:

For the new problem, just apply the previous answer, applying a sign function properly after and before the filters (that will not be shown here, left as exercise).

[image: Envelope Plots]

Comment: Hi, Thanks! This works for the question asked but I realised I was perhaps maybe to specific. I have amended the question. Do you have any other solutions? The direction of noise depends on sign of signal which changes over time

Comment: This is an entirely different problem. Are you really clear on what are you needing?...

Comment: Now the problem is different, and the answer do not hold valid anymore after answered, hence losing my time and the other people in this forum.